# Apply multipe styles on android textview kotlin extinsion strange behavior

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring

Hello I have this extension to apply the styles on the targeted words, but it doesn't work applying the styles if I send multiple words for some reason, I tested in a sample project and it works fine .. anyone could help me with it.

```
fun String.applySpans(vararg pairs: Pair<String, Any> ): Spannable {
   val spannable = SpannableStringBuilder(this)
   pairs.forEach {
        val start = this.indexOf(it.first)
        val end = start + it.first.length
        spannable.setSpan(it.second, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE)
    }
    return spannable
}
```

this is the working version in the test sample

```
val bold = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)
        val italic = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
        val string = getString(R.string.hello_message, "John", "Wick")
        testTextView.text = string.applySpans(mapOf(
                "John" to bold,
                "Wick" to italic
            )
        )
```

this is the code with the problem

```
val message = getString(R.string.not_delivery_to_this_area, searchError.restaurant, searchError.area)
              searchErrorView.errorMessage.text = message.applySpans(
                     searchError.restaurant to bold,
                   searchError.area to bold
             )
```

Comment: Have you defined
`val bold = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)` ?

Comment: yes that exactly what I did

Comment: Can you tell me the value of not_delivery_to_this_area, searchError.restaurant and searchError.area?

Comment: <string name="not_delivery_to_this_area">%s is not delivering to %s</string>

Comment: Does it work for you with just one argument? Your searchErrorView.errorMessage.text might be striping the styling.

Comment: yes, it works fine in both cases in the test sample

Comment: But in your code are you able to pass a styled string to your view?

Comment: Try passing a spanned string directly see if the spann shows up

Comment: If your view is a custom Textview it might cast your spannable to string when you set it and your spann gets ignored.

Comment: it's not a custom view